# PhpStorm 10 Download to Library issues (JS yes, CSS no)

Tags: phpstorm

I'm just wondering how I can customize the part where PhpStorm allows only to d/l jQuery or other related scripts into library, yet no CSS option to d/l into library.

[image]

Of course that the solution is to create a new file > copy the name of the filename > paste it into the name > copy the contents of the bootstrap.min link, paste it in the new created file.

I'm trying to get an automated "d/l into library" option working for CSS, which is pretty cardinal, considering the fact that **no bootstrap class hinting will appear in PhpStorm until you have a local/cached library for bootstrap**

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not yet implemented (latest stable is v2016.2).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10023 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Comment: Yes I've read the article now, thanks for the link @LazyOne, I'm just wondering why would it be so difficult to create a D/L to lib/cache option for JS files but not for CSS, is it a security issue? I mean, it's the same functionality, you just need to rule in *.css files too, am I missing something bigger here? I'm 95% sure webstorm has it, so is this some dark marketing plot? Annoying is what it is.

Comment: ?? That's not the article -- that's the actual ticket in JetBrains' Issue Tracker. It's located in WEB project (WebStorm) .. so no -- WebStorm does not have this functionality either. Why this ticket is not yet implemented and what stops devs from implementing it -- you may ask these questions JB devs directly there in a ticket. I've only gave you the answer for your question -- such functionality is not yet implemented for .css files (most likely because IDE has no concept of "CSS Libraries" like it has for JavaScript so cannot store such downloadable files outside of the project).